# How to update Vim to the newest version?

Tags: vim, centos7, youcompleteme

After I install and configure [YCM](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) on my CentOS 7 computer, I miss the YCM problem `User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found`.

So I check YCM github issues, and I find that [my vim version may be too old](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1370), I should update my vim version higher than 7.4.314 or later. So I tried serval ways:

1. Compile vim from source code([vim github](https://github.com/vim/vim)), However, I get the version 7.4.2x(I can't remember, not higher than 7.4.314)
2. yum install from EPEL testing repo(I think this repo may include the newest version), However, I got the version 7.4.160

So I really don't know how to get the newest vim version(whether form vim homepage or third party repo).

Comment: If you got the source from github, you got a version number 7.4.2000 (in other words your 2 was correct, but you got the scale wrong)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its regarding an old version of vim that is long since past. It is no longer relevant.

Comment: What about users who still have an old vim version and want to update it? This question is useful for them. They're stuck on old vim otherwise...